# How can I test my PIP for WSO2 Server

Tags: maven, wso2, xacml, wso2-identity-server

I created a PIP for WSO2 Identity Server  to get attribute value from exist-db database using Maven project and implementing AbstractPIPAttributeFinder.

Please can you tell me, How can i test my PIP if he extracts correctly Attributs from the database or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is you can write a policy with attribute id and try out policy using WSO2 Identity Server management console.  Other way...  you can start WSO2 Identity Server is debug mode and debug the your PIP attribute finder code that you have written
in UNIX, you can start as follows and debug the  "getAttributeValues" method.

> ./wso2server.sh --debug 5005

You can find more details about writing a PIP attribute finder from here [1] which would also help you..

[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2011/12/18/writing-jdbc-pip-module/